# How to have a button in MasterPage and use differently in content pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button in my MasterPage:

```
<asp:Button ID="tyt" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="tyt_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="SUBMIT A MESSAGEBOX" />
```

I want to use the button to do different thing in different pages.

I added the following in my MasterPage:

```
public void tyt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnMasterControlClick(e);
        }
        protected void OnMasterControlClick(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.MasterControlClicked != null)
            {
                this.MasterControlClicked(this, e);
            }
        }
```

The following in page1.aspx:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);

            if (this.Master is Site)
            {
                ((Site)this.Master).MasterControlClicked += new EventHandler(ContentControlClicked);
            }
        }
        private void ContentControlClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("your task");
        }
```

The following in page2.aspx:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);

            if (this.Master is Site)
            {
                ((Site)this.Master).MasterControlClicked += new EventHandler(ContentControlClicked);
            }
        }
        private void ContentControlClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("your task");
        }
```

Only `Your task` is displayed if I am on page1.aspx but when I am on page2.aspx and I press the button, the page just reloads.

How do I fix it?

Comment: I think it might be better to have a container on your master and then add the button on each page, with the propper event. Adding a new EventHandler when OnInit will make you have multiple events executing, since it is a multicast delegate

Comment: I am trying to avoid adding on each page because the button will remain the same but in different page it will do different tasks.

Comment: I agree with @pollirrata.  Additionally, while *you* know that pattern to use for this button, what is to stop someone else later on from adding a user-control (or 2 or 3) that handles the event on a page that also handles this click event?  You would have no way of knowing that someone introduced this potentially undesirable behavior and it would be difficult to debug.  If you could be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish with this code, we might be able to offer an alternative that doesn't require a container where you have to add the button on every page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using an interface.  Create an interface that defines the action or actions you need.

```
public interface IActionPage
{
    void Action();
}
```

Then have each of your pages implement the interface.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page, IActionPage
{ 
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public void Action()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("your task");
    }
}
```

Finally, have the master page's button cast the current page to the interface and then invoke the method.

```
protected void tyt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ActionPage = this.Page as IActionPage;
    if (ActionPage != null)
        ActionPage.Action();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another way of adding event handler is using delegate Action<> or Func<> for handler

in Master page.

```
public Action MyButtonCallBack {get; set;}
```

in Child page.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    if (this.Master is Site)
    {
        ((Site)this.Master).MyButtonCallBack = DoSomething;
    }
}

private void DoSomething() 
{
    //...
}
```